# Import to my python code a c library i made using swig

Tags: python, c, swig

I am trying to import a library of 2 functions I wrote in C to my code in python (using swig).

I have the following files: `OldSystem.h` `OldSystem.c` `OldSystem.i`

I have 2 functions in the header file, which I declared in the .i format file:

```
OldSystem.i:


%module OldSystem

%{
  #include "OldSystem.h"
%}

char* readOldParty(char *party_data_file);
void freeOldParty();
```

Now I want to use these functions in my python code.

I am trying to use swig, so I created the necessary wrapper file and object files .o, with this command: `swig -python OldSystem.i`

then I typed:

```
gcc -c -std=c99 -Wall -Werror -pedantic-errors -DNDEBUG -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/python3.6m *.c
```

and after that:

```
ld -shared -L/usr/local/include/python3.6m -o _OldSystem.so *.o
```

now I have all the needed files to use my C functions in python.

The issue is that when I try to import this library to python command prompt (with `import OldSystem`), I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "OldSystem.py", line 26, in <module>
    _OldSystem = swig_import_helper()
  File "OldSystem.py", line 22, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_OldSystem', fp, pathname, description)

ImportError: ./_OldSystem.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicode_FromFormat
```

Does anyone know what is the problem or where should I look for?
If any other information needed about my C code to understand it, I will add it in the comments, but basically the declarations are described above (in the file `OldSystem.i`):

```
char* readOldParty(char *party_data_file);
void freeOldParty();
```

Thanks for anyone that can help.

Comment: i write and compile my code on a linux terminal with bash and python on it, not with a grapgic IDE or windows

Comment: @Nate He meant formatting the code when asking the questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: when you edit question there is button `{}` to format selected part of text as code - and then code is highlighted.

Comment: Add `-lpython3` to your linker command